# searching two array string for equal words

Tags: arrays, perl

I am a beginner in Perl. I have two string arrays array1 and array2. I want to check the each and every element in 2nd array. if there is i want to give a relative value one to that particular element in the 2nd array. the relative values are store in an array.I try it out but it  wont work and git gives a warning like" Use of uninitialized value in string eq at pjt.pl line 52,  line 3".

```
while($i <= (scalar @resultarray-1))
{
    while ($j <= (scalar @inputsymbl-1))
    {
        if ($resultarray[$i] eq $inputsymbl[$j])
        {
            $rel[$j]=1;
            $i=$i+1;
            $j=0;
        }
        else
        {
            $j=$j+1;
        }
    }
    if($j==(scalar @inputsymbl))
    {
        $i=$i+1;
        $j=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: From the information you have provided, i would believe your problem is that you use some sort of uninitialized value. Don't do that. Seriously though, how do you expect anyone to help you with a question like that?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
my $i = 0;
my $j = 0;

## walk each array element
foreach(@resultarray) {
    my $result = $_;
    foreach(@inputsymbl) {
        my $symbl = $_;
        if ($result eq $symbl) {
            $rel[$j] = 1;
            $i++;
        } else {
            $j++;
        }
    }
    if ($j == (scalar @inputsymbl - 1)) {
        $i++;
        $j = 0;
    }
}
```

provide more informations if you need detailed help.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and code, it appears that you want to *flag* the indexes, by using a third array, of the two array's elements that are equal.  By doing this, however, you're creating a [sparse array](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/perl/0596003137/arrays/perlckbk2-chp-4-sect-4).  Also, if the two arrays don't have the same number of elements, a "Use of uninitialized value in string eq..." warning will eventually occur.  Given these issues, consider using the smaller index of the two arrays (done using the [ternary operator](http://perltricks.com/article/20/2013/4/16/The-conditional-ternary-operator) below) and `push`ing the indexes of the equal elements onto the third array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @results;
my @arr1 = qw/A B C D E F G H I J/;
my @arr2 = qw/A D C H E K L H N J P Q R S T/;
# Equal:      ^   ^   ^     ^   ^
# Index:      0   2   4     7   9

for my $i ( 0 .. ( $#arr1 <= $#arr2 ? $#arr1 : $#arr2 ) ) {
    push @results, $i if $arr1[$i] eq $arr2[$i];
}

print Dumper \@results;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          0,
          2,
          4,
          7,
          9
        ];
```

Hope this helps!